# What is the best approach to perform a two tiered aggregation?

Tags: apache-flink

I am attempting to do a tier two tiered aggregation using Flink 1.3.2, but my results appear to be not performing as expected over time.  Initially, I get expected results.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with the approach I am taking here?

I have not been able to find any good examples of others performing this type of chained operation.

```
val myStream = sourceStream
  .keyBy( 0 )      
  .timeWindow( Time.minutes(30) )
  .reduce( (r1: myRow, r2: myRow) => {  r1 + r2  },
           (key: Any, window: TimeWindow, iterable: Iterable[myRow], out: Collector[myRow]) => { out.collect(iterable.iterator.next.setWindowStart(window.getStart)) }   )
  .map(tier2Row.fromMyRow(_))
  .keyBy( 0 )        
  .timeWindow( Time.minutes(10) )
  .reduce( _ + _ )
  .addSink(new MyTier2RowSink)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Processing Time mode originally for time based data and was getting strange results.  I switched to Ingestion Time mode, and the tiered aggregates now process in the expected fashion with no changes to my code other than setting the mode.

Comment: Fabian gave me the clue in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498772/how-can-i-inspect-the-internal-flink-timestamp-for-an-item-in-a-stream-using-the